# Console command to set Lydia steward at a homestead?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I am trying to keep Farkas as my not-a-follower follower by keeping Proving Honor unfinished. Some time late in the game I decided to build a homestead and therefore need a steward.

Unfortunately, the standard way to do that is getting a follower, bringing them to the homestead, and choosing a dialog option to turn them into a steward there.

When I try to ask Lydia to follow me she says I first need to dismiss any existing followers, but Farkas is not a follower: he is with me as part of the quest which I am happily abusing. So I can't dismiss him in any other way but completing the quest.

Is there a way to make Lydia (or anyone else) the steward at my homestead without letting Farkas go due to Proving Honor ending?